# Prove limit at $-\infty$ using definition

Tags: real-analysis, limits

I'd like to prove that $$\lim_{x\to-\infty} \frac{2|x|}{1+x} = -2.$$ More precisely, I'm having trouble isolating $x$ in the inequality $$\left|\frac{2|x|}{1+x} + 2\right| < \epsilon.$$
How might I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since $x\to -\infty$, we may assume that $x<-1$. Hence $1+x<0$ and
$$\left|\frac{2|x|}{1+x} + 2\right| =\left|\frac{-2x}{1+x} + 2\right|=\frac{2}{|1+x|}= \frac{2}{-1-x}\stackrel{?}{<}\epsilon.$$ 
Can you take it from here?

Comment: +1: Why did you not rewrite $|1+x|=-1-x?

Comment: @MrYouMath Good point!

Comment: How do you get to the conclusion that $|1+x| = -1-x$?

Comment: Recall that $|z|=-z$ iff $z\leq 0$.

Comment: That cleared up everything, thanks! I couldn't proceed earlier because I didn't know that I could assume $x < -1$ and I had forgotten (stupidly) that fact about absolute values...

Comment: @Taliant Well done!!

Answer (score 0):

$y:= -x.$

Consider:

$\lim_{y \rightarrow \infty} \dfrac{2y}{1-y}$.

$\star$): $0 \le |\dfrac{2y}{1-y} +2| \le |\dfrac{2}{y-1}| \le$

$|\dfrac{4}{y}|$ for $y \gt 2.$

(Used: $y-1 \gt (1/2)y$ for $y \gt 2)$.

Let $(y_n)_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$ be a sequence with

$\lim (y_n)_{n\in \mathbb{N}} \rightarrow \infty.$

For $M \in \mathbb{R^+}$ there is a $n_0$ such that

$y_n \gt M$ for $n\ge n_0.$

Let $\epsilon \gt 0$ be given.

Choose $M$ such that $4/M \lt \epsilon$.

Using $\star):$

$|\dfrac{2y_n}{1-y_n} +2| \lt \dfrac{4}{|y_n|} \lt$

$4/M \lt \epsilon$  for  $n \ge n_0$.